# Want to enforce the visitor to load the new version of your stylesheets and scripts

Tags: cache

Want to enforce the visitor to load the new version of your stylesheets and scripts

Comment: Your question is not enough to understand that what you need. Please describe it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to enforce the visitor to load the new version of your stylesheets and scripts, then (as @majick suggested) changing the version via query string is the way to go. This is just how the caching works.

My suggestion would be to make sure you update the theme version on every major, or crucial CSS and JS update, and use the theme version in the `wp_enqueue_script` version arg (which is how most themes do it).

In case it's a development issue (sometimes the caching gets in the way), you could consider making use of the `SCRIPT_DEBUG` constant, which you can set in your `wp-config.php` file. This is actually used to get a non-minified version of a file for development purposes, but you could use it to add a version to your `wp_enqueue_scripts` action like this:

```
$theme = wp_get_theme();
$theme_version = $theme->get( 'Version' );
$dev_version = filemtime( get_template_directory_uri() . '/path/to.js' );

$version = ( defined( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG' ) && SCRIPT_DEBUG ) ? $dev_version : $theme_version;

wp_enqueue_scripts( 'your-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/path/to.js', array(), $version );
```

This way you could set it for all enqueues, and you would only have to change the setting in your `wp-config.php` file.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you are talking about cachebusting.  Changing the querystring makes the browser interpret the URL as a new resource. Unless you want to change the entire filename there really isn't a better way to do this.

Use the `$ver` argument of `wp_enqueue_script` and `wp_enqueue_style` to make it easier. You could even set `$ver = time()` to force download everytime, however it is probably preferable to use the `filemtime` of the filepath for the best of both worlds - refreshing the resource only when it has actually changed.

Comment: i know how to do this using filetime,but i don't want to use query strings

Comment: if i use filetime css file apears like styles.css?73294329432 , the problem is i want to do it in a way so it appear normally like styles.css

Comment: it should be more like styles.css?ver=73294329432 but anyway, why do you want to do this? short answer is as said, there isn't another way to get around browser caching, sorry.

Comment: query string effect score of page

Comment: @MayankKapahi -- This question/answer might help: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/106195/does-a-cache-busting-fingerprint-in-image-file-names-hurt-seo-rankings

Comment: @MayankKapahi No search engine cares if your CSS file has a query string... If you don't want to use a query string you need to look into caching options with your webserver (e.g. entity tags)